# tableau custom color pallete .. anyone know why this isn't working

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, business-intelligence

I've edited the tableau pref file with the following, any thoughts on what's wrong here?

I've edited the preferences file in the repository with the snippet below, but it's not appearing in desktop.

```
<workbook>
<preferences>
<color-palette name="Test" type="regular" >
    <color>#55efc4</color>
    <color>#00b894</color>
    <color>#ffeaa7</color>
    <color>#fdcb6e</color>
    <color>#81ecec</color>
    <color>#00cec9</color>
    <color>#fab1a0</color>
    <color>#e17055</color>
    <color>#74b9ff</color>
<color>#0984e3</color>
<color>#ff7675</color>
<color>#d63031</color>
<color>#a29bfe</color>
<color>#6c5ce7</color>
<color>#b2bec3</color>
<color>#2d3436</color>

</color-palette>



</preferences>

</workbook>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted Tableau? It won't work until you do.

Also, please double check if you're editing the right repository (sometimes they may be misplaced when updating Tableau versions). Check you current rep folder on File > Repository folder